# Ajax in hibernate project

Tags: java, ajax, hibernate

Has anybody used ajax in hibernate project ? Any pointers, help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You might be referring to the [open session in view problem](https://www.hibernate.org/43.html), but your question is a bit too minimal at this point.

As for me: Yes I have used Ajax & Hibernate in the same project using Wicket, and I haven't run into any problems (when taking the above into account).

Comment: Thanks Tim, No I am not running into any problem. But I want to use ajax in hibernate for the first time, so I was looking for documentation.

Answer (score 4):

AJAX and Hibernate are not related almost at all. They might become partially related in the context of one framework or another. The flow would look like that:

`Hibernate (fetches entities) -> service layer (manipulates the result) -> controller (serializes the objects to xml/json/whatever) -> ajax (displays the result dynamically)`

You see, there are many steps between hibernate and ajax. You will eventually bump into a problem, which was already mentioned and is solved by the `open-session-in-view`.

Comment: I never said they are related. I want to use ajax in my hibernate project. How does that mean they are related?

Comment: because they appear in the same question. If you want to know how to use either of them separately, mention it explicitly. Would it make sense if I ask you "how to use transactions and html" ?

Comment: Well , my question is straight forward if someone has used Ajax in hibernate project. Neither of them separately because I know how to use them separately. I am using hibernate for web application with plain javascript till date. I wanted some dynamic features and that's why I turned to Ajax.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that. And I'm sure lots of people have done it. And you've got some pointers already. The ones that say "There's no relationship between the two" are good pointers. Because AJAX is Javascript. It doesn't make the least bit of difference to code running on the server (i.e. Hibernate) how the HTTP requests were generated on the client. So the only possible "pointer" is to ask why you think there's a question.

Comment: I'm with yogsma on this one.  Hibernate & AJAX are related, just like HTML & PHP/Java/Ruby is related.  If you don't see the relationship then I'll paint the picture for you.  Use XmlHttpRequest object to make a POST HTTP call to a Java Servlet.  BOOM, you want to access your database via hibernate.  See the relation?  Even Apples & Oranges have a relation.

Comment: @John Strickler yeah, they are fruits. And ajax and hibernate are..software technologies. A mop and a spoon are both used in the kitchen, but I don't think "How to use a mop and a spoon" makes any sense. Furthermore, what you 'showed' me is already in my answer. I've indicated the whole flow from client to database. But that still doesn't mean there is anything specific to the two technologies in combination. As @Paul Clapham noted - it doesn't matter how the request is generated, so even the OSIV pattern is not something specific to ajax.

Comment: Fruits... yea.  Anyhow, I'm running into issues using hibernate & ajax together.  Even though they are clearly not related.  Hibernate is expensive - making multiple quick AJAX calls to a servlet that uses hibernate causes some unexpected results.  Although, why am I talking about AJAX & Hibernate in the same sentence?  That is just crazy talk.

Comment: @John Strickler this is heave usage of the application, again not inherent to ajax per-se. My advice in that case is to make use of caching (query cache, 2nd level cache). But you should do that with or without ajax.

Comment: and also - the performance problem would be there even with plain jdbc.

Answer (score 1):

We use both every day.

However, the two technologies are not related, they don't interact.

So there is nothing specific, you can just use each... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too generic as you have not included information about what exactly you are having a problem with.

So based on my understanding, I will give you a brief of what each of these technologies does and how are they related:

Consider a website which allows you to retrieve and persist employee details to a database from your web browser. The way browser communicates to your server will be AJAX (If you do not know what is AJAX, I'd suggest you to read more and enlighten yourself on it).

Now, the AJAX-based request has reached your server, which will employee another Java technology called a "Web service" which will receive this data and based on business logic, it will decide whether to query the DB and what to query it for.

Every database will implement different flavors for SQL, so you cannot change keep changing your project's core for every database. So we use Hibernate to provide an fuss-free, direct communication layer to different types of databases at once. All you now need to change when migrating form one database to another is your connection string and the driver you are using (both in a hibernate configuration file - hibernate.cfg.xml).